# Notifications for answers to favourite questions

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

I have noticed that there are no notifications sent for answers to favourite questions. For instance, I see an interesting question and add it to the favourites list. However, if the question has no answer at that point in time I will not be notified if an answer is provided later.

Would it be possible to add notifications for these answers(I don't want to keep 30+ tabs opened in my browser)?

Comment: You'll see changed ones marked, when you [view them in your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1079483/sebi?tab=favorites)

Comment: Here's a better illustration of what @πάνταῥεῖ was trying to point out: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Joy8.png,  The caveat is indicator doesn't only show answers, but all activity on a post (including edits).  This is better IMO since you can stay up to date on everything and not just new answers.

Comment: I see that,but it still doesn't show which questions have been provided answers, or the new answers given for that matter(at least in my case)

Comment: With your proposal active, wouldn't we just end up spending all our time going through many notifications - reading questions which have changed in some way etc?

Comment: [StackEye - Chrome Extension to follow users and questions on StackExchange sites](http://stackapps.com/q/4454/10590)

Comment: @James Obviously not. In the question I mentioned that notifications should be made only if answers are given; other modifications such as edits can be safely ignored if provided answers are satisfactory. Also, questions have a fairly short lifespan on stackoverflow(or any stack exchange sites for that matter); usually users no longer answer if the op has already accepted one previously.

Comment: I suppose it depends on why you use the fave question feature. I don't find any use for it to be honest. I come here to answer and comment to help out. If a question has no answer and I can answer it then I make an answer, otherwise I leave it to others. You surely cannot be waiting for answers to questions, so am quite intrigued as to how you use the fave Q feature.

Comment: @James That is a rather subjective assertion you are making viewed from a single stand point and not necessarily applicable to all so. users. I come here when I've exhausted most means of finding a solution to a problem, usually when stringent time constraints are set. So, to answer your question: no, I am not waiting for answers; so. is simply another potential source of information to me. Sometimes some questions spark my interest more than others thus I favourite them. I do not specifically expect an answer but am interested in one if provided.

Comment: Just trying to find out if there is a really good reason the proposal could be valid & useful to other users. I'm not against the idea, & not voted either way, but as it stands I don't see much argument for implementing it other than it could be useful to you & possibly a few other users. The site usually considers change or new features when it's beneficial for *many* users (there are millions of us...). Some users won't want their notification bar *spammed* when they just bookmark a question for later viewing. So it'll ideally need per-user settings, which likely won't happen.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237036/inbox-notification-when-a-favourite-question-has-new-activity see that, the duped links, and various other links in those questions for further info and others' views on it

Comment: I would add also notifications for comment, edits, even votes for the questions I'm interested in